# Merge duplicated records in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, merge, duplicates

I have a pyspark dataframe that have duplicated ids. There are missing values in some of the records and differences in the "Time" field among the duplicated ids.

```
+-------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
|id            |Time                   |Type                     |Status|
+-------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
|1            |2020-03-01             |                          |                                 |
|1            |2020-03-01             |A                         |Single                           |
|1            |2020-03-01             |A                         |                                 |
|2            |2020-02-01             |C                         | Double                          |
|2            |2020-02-25             |                          | Double                          |
+-------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

How can I merge the info in every field and make them into one record? And if there is there are difference "time"value, how can i just choose the most recent one? The ideal dataframe looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
    |id            |Time                   |Type                     |Status|
    +-------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+
    |1            |2020-03-01             |A                         | Single                     |             
    |2            |2020-02-25             |C                         | Double                     |                      
    +-------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------------
```

And please note that I have around 100 fields in this dataframe, not just the four I am showing.

Answer (score 0):

Try by grouping by **`id`** then get the **max(time)** by converting to date type to get most recent one.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+----------+----+------+
#| id|      Time|Type|Status|
#+---+----------+----+------+
#|  1|2020-03-01|    |      |
#|  1|2020-03-01|   A|Single|
#|  1|2020-03-01|   A|      |
#|  2|2020-02-01|   C|Double|
#|  2|2020-02-25|    |Double|
#+---+----------+----+------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

expr=[max(to_date(f'{i}')).alias("Time") for i in df.columns if i == 'Time'] +[max(f'{i}').alias(f'{i}') for i in df.columns if i not in ['id','Time']]
#[Column<b'max(to_date(`Time`)) AS `Time`'>, Column<b'max(Type) AS `Type`'>, Column<b'max(Status) AS `Status`'>]

df.groupBy("id").agg(*expr).show()
#+---+----------+----+------+
#| id|      Time|Type|Status|
#+---+----------+----+------+
#|  1|2020-03-01|   A|Single|
#|  2|2020-02-25|   C|Double|
#+---+----------+----+------+
```

If you want to get **`first/last`** based on `Type,Status` values then

```
when_expr=['id'] + [when(length(f'{i}') ==0 ,lit(None)).otherwise(col(f'{i}')).alias(f'{i}') for i in df.columns if i not in ['id']]

df1=df.select(*when_expr)

df1.show()
#+---+----------+----+------+
#| id|      Time|Type|Status|
#+---+----------+----+------+
#|  1|2020-03-01|null|  null|
#|  1|2020-03-01|   A|Single|
#|  1|2020-03-01|   A|  null|
#|  2|2020-02-01|   C|Double|
#|  2|2020-02-25|null|Double|
#+---+----------+----+------+

#using first function
expr=[max(to_date(f'{i}')).alias("Time") for i in df.columns if i == 'Time'] +[first(f'{i}',True).alias(f'{i}') for i in df.columns if i not in ['id','Time']]

#using last function
expr=[max(to_date(f'{i}')).alias("Time") for i in df.columns if i == 'Time'] +[last(f'{i}',True).alias(f'{i}') for i in df.columns if i not in ['id','Time']]

df1.groupBy("id").agg(*expr).show()
#+---+----------+----+------+
#| id|      Time|Type|Status|
#+---+----------+----+------+
#|  1|2020-03-01|   A|Single|
#|  2|2020-02-25|   C|Double|
#+---+----------+----+------+
```